# What is lim n→∞ (2)^(1/n)? Why is it equal to 1?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

What is lim n→∞ (2)^(1/n)? Why is it equal to 1? All proofs shown are about n^(1/n) or something like this form. What about 2?

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty }\tfrac1n = 0$ and $2^0=1$.

Comment: do you want epsilon proof?

Comment: $n >\frac 1 {\log_2(1+\epsilon)} $ implies that $|2^{1/n}-1| <\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$
So, $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} 2^{\frac{1}{n}}=2^{0}=1$
As denominator gets bigger and bigger while numerator being constant then fraction gets closer and closer to zero.

Answer (score 0):

As the base $b=2$ is a constant,

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 2^{(1/n)} = 2^{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1/n)} = 2^0 = 1.$